# How to count fields based on flags in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am creating a pivot table based on a data set with Yes/No flags for the different available options.

Below is my data set.

[image: Excel Data]

Once I put this data into a pivot table I have been trying to get the count of each option based on their region, but I can't seem to find out how to count each option based on if the option is Y/N.

I have looked into calculated fields and think this might be a way to get this done, but I'm not sure.

I want to do create this pivot table without adding any fields to the original data set.

Below is a picture of what I had in mind for the pivot table, but the counts were off.

[image: Pivot Table Problem]

Comment: So you want to count Y as 1 and N as 0?

Comment: Yes I would like a SUM of Each Option based on their Region.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix this will be to add additional columns to calculate the totals you need. So in Column H, you could add a title Option1_Yes and this formula in H2:

```
=IF(D2="Y",1,0)
```

If you fill that down and right you can create the other values you need. Just make sure to extend the range of your Pivot Table Data Source to include the new columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is crosstabulated, because of the multiple columns all related to option. (Option 1, Option 2, ...., Option n). PivotTables don't like Crosstabs where 'related' column headers run across the top. You need to "unpivot" your data first, which means changing it from a CrossTab to what's known as a Flat File.

If you've got the PowerQuery add-in installed (or have Excel 2016 or Excel/Office 365 subscription) then you can use PowerQuery to do this. Google "PowerQuery" and "Unpivot" and you'll turn up a whole heap of videos.

Otherwise you can use VBA such as my Unpivot routine I've previously blogged about at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and quickest way to fix this is to replace "y" flags with numeric 1 and leave N flags as blank.